# Anyone know how to fix the new OAuth2 error when trying to authenticate a PyDrive application?

Tags: google-oauth, pydrive

I don't think this issue is specific to PyDrive, but rather Google OAuth. However, some of the solutions I've seen on stackoverflow don't seem to be transferable over to my PyDrive application, which is just a python script to upload files programmatically to a shared drive. It worked fine 2 months ago but I tried to rerun it today and it's not working. Here is the error I'm getting:

```
Authorisation Error
Error 400: invalid_request
You can't sign in to this app because it doesn't comply with Google's OAuth 2.0 policy for keeping apps secure.

You can let the app developer know that this app doesn't comply with one or more Google validation rules.
Request Details
The content in this section has been provided by the app developer. This content has not been reviewed or verified by Google.
If you’re the app developer, make sure that these request details comply with Google policies.
redirect_uri: urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob
```

I am using a web application OAuth 2.0 Client ID creds on GCP. All secrets are stored in a local client_secrets.json file.

I run my script, it sends a message to the console that says

```
Go to the following link in your browser:

    https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=blahblahblah.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=urn%3Aietf%3Awg%3Aoauth%3A2.0%3Aoob&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.googleapis.com%2Fauth%2Fdrive&access_type=offline&response_type=code

Enter verification code:
```

How it used to work: After I click the link above, it returns a code I paste into the console and then its authenticated. FYI: I plan on running this 24/7 on a remote server.

Now: I click the link above and get the error I posted above. I've tried to change the redirect uri to 127.0.0.1 and it does allow me to auth, then I get a code in my URL, but once I copy that and paste it into the console, I get more errors.

Anyone know the solution for this?

Comment: I am facing the same issue in php-google ads api.

Comment: FYI: I fixed mine by adding a redirect URI in the GCP console under my app.

Comment: @AnthonyQuinn Redirect from `urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob` to `where`? (i.e. what is the whole point of the redirect URI anyway?)  thx.